# Switch case and dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, java

[image]

I am writing code to get state value from the drop-down and depending upon the state calculating the tax rate. I am using switch case statement to define the tax rate for each state. 
I want to use selected state in the switch case statement, how I can do it.

Here is my code:

```
Select stateSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlState")));    
stateSelect.selectByVisibleText(state);

double dl; 
double taxrate =0; 
switch(*****) // What I can write here inorder to get selected state
{ 
    case "British Columbia":
         taxrate = 0.05;
         break; 

    case "Alberta":
         taxrate = 0.10;
         break; 
        // And so on.....
} 
taxprice= pprice*taxrate;
```

Comment: `String selectedOption = stateSelect.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();` return selected option but I don't understand why you want to set option and then get option...

Answer (score 1):

'state' variable holds the name of the state you are about to select. Simply use this variable in switch statement.

```
switch(state){
  //cases
}
```